# How to post a rest api request with Key:Value multipart/form-data using karate

Tags: multipartform-data, karate

I want to post a request which is multipart/form-data. But it has body which is Key:value pair. It is working in Postman, soapui and parasoft soatest. Below is the code which i tried.

```
Given url 'http://localhost:8080/services/oauth2/token'
And multipart field username=username@usernmae
And multipart field password=secertePass
And multipart client_secret=98765432d1
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
When method post
Then status 200
```

Error in karate:
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: test.feature:9 - no step-definition method match found for: multipart field grant_type=password
    at ✽.And multipart field grant_type=password (test.feature:9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not providing space before and after `=` can cause this, also field missed in client secret.

Have you tried,

```
And multipart field username = username@usernmae 
And multipart field password = secertePass 
And multipart field client_secret = 98765432d1
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes providing space before and after = resolved the issue